# How to remove the 'Edit Translation' text from Transposh

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to remove the 'Edit Translation' text from Transposh. I'm just going to leave the translations as is.

I'm trying to add css like such:

```
#transposh-3:nth-child(8){display:none;}
```

and

```
localizertextnode{display:none;}
```

but they don't seem to be working. Any ideas?

I know this is more to do with WordPress but I'm trying to use CSS to fix this, which is a coding language so I thought this might just scrape by the standards.

Also, there's way more traffic on overflow than there is on WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a very late answer but I stumbled upon the same problem. Maybe it can help others in the future.

In the source files of the plugin, edit next file:
wp-content/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/wp/transposh_widget.php

On line 301- 306 edit following code

```
if ($this->transposh->is_editing_permitted()) {
  $ref = transposh_utils::rewrite_url_lang_param($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $this->transposh->home_url, $this->transposh->enable_permalinks_rewrite, ($this->transposh->options->is_default_language($this->transposh->target_language) ? "" : $this->transposh->target_language), !$this->transposh->edit_mode);
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . EDIT_PARAM . '" value="1" ' .
  ($this->transposh->edit_mode ? 'checked="checked" ' : '') .
  ' onclick="document.location.href=\'' . $ref . '\';"/>&nbsp;Edit Translation';
 }
```

And change it to

```
if ($this->transposh->is_editing_permitted()) {
  $ref = transposh_utils::rewrite_url_lang_param($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $this->transposh->home_url, $this->transposh->enable_permalinks_rewrite, ($this->transposh->options->is_default_language($this->transposh->target_language) ? "" : $this->transposh->target_language), !$this->transposh->edit_mode);
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . EDIT_PARAM . '" value="1" ' .
  ($this->transposh->edit_mode ? 'checked="checked" ' : '') .
  ' onclick="document.location.href=\'' . $ref . '\';"/><p class="edittranslationtext">&nbsp;Edit Translation</p>';
}
```

I simply added a p element with class name edittranslationtext in there. In your Custom CSS you can add now:

```
.edittranslationtext {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks great to me. It's been so long since I put this up that I can't really remember what I did here, but I just visited the site I was building and the text I wanted to remove isn't on the page, so I must have fixed it. I think I found that code and commented it out, but I can't really remember. Just thought I'd ad this comment in case anyone is looking for this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am the plugin author. Just stumbled upon this question, years after it was written, but seeing that the simplest answer is missing, I will just write it here.

All you need to do is to change the editing permissions, this will remove the text. The easiest way is to remove anonymous users access, which will lead to only admins and translators seeing this text at all.

GL